# The functionality of updates in theano.function

Tags: theano

I am trying to understand the following piece of theano code.

```
self.sgd_step = theano.function(
            [x, y, learning_rate, theano.Param(decay, default=0.9)],
            [], 
            updates=[(E, E - learning_rate * dE / T.sqrt(mE + 1e-6)),
                     (U, U - learning_rate * dU / T.sqrt(mU + 1e-6)),
                     (W, W - learning_rate * dW / T.sqrt(mW + 1e-6)),
                     (V, V - learning_rate * dV / T.sqrt(mV + 1e-6)),
                     (b, b - learning_rate * db / T.sqrt(mb + 1e-6)),
                     (c, c - learning_rate * dc / T.sqrt(mc + 1e-6)),
                     (self.mE, mE),
                     (self.mU, mU),
                     (self.mW, mW),
                     (self.mV, mV),
                     (self.mb, mb),
                     (self.mc, mc)
])
```

Can someone please tell me, what the author of the above code is trying to do there? There is a value, `[x, y, learning_rate, theano.Param(decay, default=0.9)]` trying to be updated, and the value is gonna be updated by `[]`? And what is the function of `updates` here?

I would be so grateful if I can have an idea what is going on in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the `updates` is as follows (taken from [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#using-shared-variables)).

> updates must be supplied with a list of pairs of the form (shared-variable, new expression). It can also be a dictionary whose keys are shared-variables and values are the new expressions. Either way, it means “whenever this function runs, it will replace the .value of each shared variable with the result of the corresponding expression”. Above, our accumulator replaces the state‘s value with the sum of the state and the increment amount.

So when you call the above theano function with the required inputs, it will update values of shared variables, namely `E, U, W, V, b, c, ..., self.mc`. The new value to be updated is given by the second quantity in the tuple. Basically, `E = E - learning_rate * dE / T.sqrt(mE + 1e-6)` and so on.